# Can't fetch files from mongoDB using gridFS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, gridfs-stream, multer-gridfs-storage

```
const mongoURI = process.env.MONGOURL;
const connection = await mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);
connection.once('open', () => {
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
})
app.get('/files', (req, res) => {
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
  if (!conn) return res.status(500).send({
    message: "connect timeout",
    success: false
  })
  if (connection) console.log("starting")
  gfs.files.find().toArray((err, files) => {
    console.log("in")
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Error retrieving the files",
        error: err
      });
    }
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: "No files found"
      });
    }
    else {
      files.map(file => {
        if (
          file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ||
          file.contentType === 'image/png'
        ) {
          file.isImage = true;
        } else {
          file.isImage = false;
        }
      });
      res.render('dashboard', { files: files });
    }
  });
});
```

this is my code, and my **toArray function is getting depricated**, and if remove the var gfs line from the app.get("/files"), i am getting "cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'files')"

i refered to **[GridFS TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70575758/gridfs-typeerror-cannot-read-property-files-of-undefined)** to solve the error, but now my toArray function is getting depricated. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

1. You use initialized gfs outside the connnection.once and try using GridFSBucket

> ```
> var gfs; conn.once('open', () => {
>     gfs = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(conn.db, {
>         bucketName: 'images',
>     }); });
> ```

2. In routes you do not need to redeclare gfs, try using async rather than callback.

```
const file = await gfs.find({ _id }).toArray()`
try console.log the file to check
```

Comment: the second point worked, thanks. but i didn't understand what you meant by the first point

Comment: @AyushTripathi What I mean by first point is related to variable scope, it is best to define the variabe outside the function first in order to use it in other places.